# How to delete a Gitorious repository

Tags: gitorious

I have a working private Gitorious server. Under project `my_proj` I created two repositories `my_repo1` and `my_repo2`. I would like to delete the later repository but can't seem to find how to do it.

The repository's owner is `+my_group (through ~my_user)` and I am an admin in this group.

**How can I delete the repository?**

UPDATE:

- When I click on `my_repo2` I don't have a an 'Edit Repository' option even though I'm an admin in `my_group`
- I just upgraded from Gitorious 2.1.0 to 2.2.1 and the problem persists

Answer (score 3):

Go to my_proj.

You would see my_repo1 and my_repo2 listed there.

Click on my_repo2 or the repo that you want to delete.

Click Edit Repository, and on the Right Hand side you would see delete repository. Click it and confirm, should work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: When I click on `my_repo2` I don't have a `Edit Repository` even though I'm an admin in `my_group`

Answer (score 0):

There is a python script called `gmkrepo` to create and delete a repo from command line. This can be helpful to you.